# Tengo un error con la librería compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'

Tags: android, android-studio

Al momento de incluir la libería:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
```

en mi app/build.gradle me lanza el error:

> this support library should not use a different version (25) than the compilesdkversion (24)

¿Alguien sabe por qué?

Comment: Sube la versión de compileSdkVersion 24 a compileSdkVersion 25 i el targetSdkVersion 25

Comment: ahora me lanza un error en esta libreria compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1' ,  y cuando sincronizo me sale un error que dice .... Error:Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25' in: C:\Users\jorge\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
<a href="install.android.platform">Install missing platform(s) and sync project</a>

Comment: es que si ponen compileSdkVersion 25 todo lo debes subir a 25, alt+intro en la linea donde te da error el mismo te pondrá la versión correcta

Comment: a vaya entiendo, solo ahora me lanza un error en las clases java, en donde va esta linea package com.example.jorge.chatapp;

Comment: el error que me envia en el package es este:  .... the sdk platform-tools version (24.0.4) is too old to check apis compiled with api 25; please update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder usar la versión 25 de las librerias de soporte de Google, debes tener la versión del SDK 25 y tener configurado lo siguiente.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        targetSdkVersion 25

y después todas las dependencias de la librerías de soporte a 25

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
    ...
```

Te puede solicitar que se debe instalar el SDK 25, sale en donde se muestra los errores.

Comment: vaya gracias, entendi perfectamente y me funciono muy bien, solo la duda que me queda es que en las clases que tengo en la  primer linea donde se declara el package, en mi caso esta linea package com.example.jorge.chatapp; ... me sale subrayado en rojo, puedo crear el apk sin errores pero me sigue saliendo subrayado en rojo como si fuera error y al pasar el cursor me dice este mensaje:  the sdk platform-tools version (24.0.4) is too old to check apis compiled with api 25; please update ...simplemente no le hago caso? o tengo que cambiar alguna versión mas?

Comment: Ahora estoy haciendo pruebas, veo que buildToolsVersion existen la versión 25, subela 25.0.0 saldra el error y instalar el paquete